# Implement Woocommerce POST Request in android

Tags: android, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am developing Android Application and using woocommerce REST API i am able to fetch products and display them in android app

But i am not able to create order and customer using POST method in android. I have gone through documentation and all available things but not found something related to POST method in android.

Can anyone provide me the sample code for implementing POST request in Android?

Answer (score 1):

There's very little context here, What are u Developing the app in? Hard to give u a Post Request in "Android" Are u talking Native Android? Java? I mean its kinda to broad.

But as for the HTTP/HTTPS Request Are u using the correct CURL?

```
curl -X POST https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products
```